How To Dynamically Insert Table into MS Teams Chat and Outlook Email Steps with JSON Data
​I am building a process where people can submit between 1 - 20 Power BI reports for internal review.
As part of that process, I am wanting to implement the following:

Create a MS Teams chat with the Flow Bot between the requestor and
reviewer for faster collaboration
Create an Outlook email between the requestor, reviewer, and admin
that a review has been requested so that it can be attached in
ServiceNow

I already have a step in Power Automate which creates a filtered list of JSON values, which will be the unique reports that have been requested for review. I'm then taking that JSON and setting an array variable ("Non-EmptyReports") with that finalized array, and here's what the output looks like.
​​​​​​​{
   "name":"Non-EmptyReports",
   "value":[
      {
         "PBIReport1":"https://app.powerbi.com/groups/group1/reports/report1/ReportSectionf1?experience=power-bi",
         "PBIReport2":"https://app.powerbi.com/groups/group1/reports/report1/ReportSectionf1?experience=power-bi"
      }
   ]
}

I would like to dynamically insert a table into a MS Teams Chat and Outlook email with these values. There could be anywhere from 1 - 20 values in this array, so I cannot define a table with a set number of rows within it. I would like to build the table like this:



Report Url(s)




https://app.powerbi.com/groups/group1/reports/report1/ReportSectionf1?experience=power-bi


https://app.powerbi.com/groups/group1/reports/report2/ReportSectionf1?experience=power-bi|



I know that MS Teams and Outlook will require different setups since MS Teams can use an Adaptive Card and Outlook would need HTML. It would be great if there's any possibility that a single template can be used between both of them, but I am unsure if this is possible. It would also be great if they could be formatted as hyperlinks to make it easier to get to the links within the browser.
Any help/advice would be greatly appreciated!
​

You’ve already worked out a couple of things so can I ask, what’s the specific problem? It sounds like you just need to work through it.

@Skin the problem I'm having is that I am unable to locate any information on populating dynamically built tables from JSON. I can find tons of documentation on creating hard-coded tables with a specific number of rows/columns, but nothing for cards or HTML that will let me insert it dynamically within the body of a message. I really just need a header row, then the "value:" items listed underneath it for the messages, and would really like to format them as hyperlinks if possible.

Ahhh, right, ok.  Looping is they key but before that, your variable doesn't look quite right.  That's not an array as I'd expect it, that's a single item array with a bunch of dynamic properties that have the relevant URL's as values of each property.  Is that seriously how it's stored?  I'd expect something more like ... [ "https://app.powerbi.com/groups/group1/reports/report1/ReportSectionf1?experience=power-bi", "https://app.powerbi.com/groups/group1/reports/report2/ReportSectionf1?experience=power-bi" ] ... something like that.

If what you've shown is how it's stored then I think there's another question that precedes the one of asking how to build the table dynamically. You need to know how to loop over the properties in the object which is the first item of the array. So question, are the fields always PBIReport#?

Here's a simple flow with which you can retrieve the URLs without having a limit on the number of rows and create a dynamic table for teams message and outlook.
The output message is like this

You can use this same message to an outlook email body. Works same.
Note: this method does not depend upon the field names 'PBREport1' or any other thing. It parses the attributes of 'value' array
Steps:

JSON > declare your JSON or variable (can be output of a connection)

Compose > extract URL(s) as an array from the JSON
split(replace(string(outputs('JSON')?['value']?[0]),'}',''),',')


Select > Create an array of objects with the extracted list for parsing.
replace(last(split(replace(string(item()),' ',''),'":"')),'"','')


Create a HTML Table > for a formatted look.


Create a message for teams/outlook.



Here's the final structure of the Flow.


Thanks for the detailed solution! Unfortunately, I'm having an issue with the first compose step. For some reason, the raw input into the step is only a pair of quotes like it's not reading in the input from the JSON step even though the output from that step looks identical to your last screenshot.
[
""
]
